# Having trouble integrating with Gamma function.

Tags: integration, statistics, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

I am trying to find an expected value by integration. Not sure if it is hopeless but the statistics part is not that important in this case, rather I want to see if this integral does have a nice anti-derivative. I am sadly not too familiar with gamma function properties besides the very simple properties.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\frac{(n\beta)^{n\alpha}}{\Gamma(n\alpha)}x^{-n\alpha-1}e^{-\frac{n\beta}{x}}dx $$

As usual pulling out constants and adding exponents for same base.

$$\frac{(n\beta)^{n\alpha}}{\Gamma(n\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-n\alpha-2}e^{-\frac{n\beta}{x}}dx $$

But this is where I do not know how to continue, I tried following this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3650717/633922 post, but I am unsure if it is correct or if it even applies in my case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take $n\beta/x=y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $n\beta/x=y$ getting$$I=\frac{(n\beta)^{-1}}{\Gamma(n\alpha)}\int_0^\infty y^{n\alpha} e^{-y}dy=\frac{\Gamma(n\alpha+1)}{n\beta\Gamma(n\alpha)}$$What property of the Gamma function can you use to simplify the numerator?

> For $x>0,\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ giving you the answer $\alpha/\beta$.

---

**Edit:** Expanding on my answer, $dx=-n\beta~dy/y^2$ so$$\begin{align*}I&=\frac{(n\beta)^{n\alpha}}{\Gamma(n\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-n\alpha-2}e^{-\frac{n\beta}{x}}dx\\&=\frac{(n\beta)^{n\alpha}}{\Gamma(n\alpha)}\int^0_{\infty}\left(\frac{n\beta}y\right)^{-n\alpha-2}e^{-y}\left[\frac{-n\beta}{y^2}\right]dy\\&=\frac{(n\beta)^{-1}}{\Gamma(n\alpha)}\int_0^\infty y^{n\alpha} e^{-y}dy\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you Shubham! I am wondering how do you go about making $(x)^{-n\alpha-2}$ into $y^{n\alpha}$?

Comment: @Mobius.Drip See the edit.

Comment: I appreciate that! Thank you for your time! This makes a lot more sense now. It was just basic substitutions I feel silly. The gamma just was scaring me.